# javascript dynamic realtime grid

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, websocket, real-time, real-time-updates

I am currently looking at building a grid that is dynamically updated using web sockets. We are looking at kendo grid as an option but this does not seem to play very well if you want the data displayed to be paginated and things like sorting/filtering/grouping to be done on the server side while keeping the dynamic updates flowing in.

This can be easily achieved when updates are sent for an existing row in the grid but when a new row is added and filtering/grouping/sorting is applied with pagination there is no way of knowing on which page that row belongs too.

Any suggestions/ideas on how this could be done are very welcome.

Thanks

Comment: What server are you using, and what data at what volume are you sending?

Comment: server side  is built in java. In terms of volume there will be around 100,000 rows with 40-50 columns per row. Some of these columns are calculated upon changes to underlaying data. Ideally we would like to have pagination to handle the data size and provide a speedy interaction to users.